# VPN not working for sites outside of private network

Tags: 20.04, vpn, openvpn

I am a bit Ubuntu newbie when it comes to networking and I am currently running into strange issues with my VPN setup.

We are using OpenVPN in my company and I can download the `configuration.opvn` file. I did so and imported it into the Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) settings which created a new VPN that I can switch on.

The problem is, that I am able to access only the sites on that private network (so I can reach `mycompany.xyz`) but I cannot connect to `example.org` which is on the public web (cannot even ping it).

I am not sure how to troubleshoot it so I will be glad for any suggestion.

```
$ ip route list
default via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.0.0/11 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
10.107.0.0/16 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
10.140.0.0/16 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
10.224.0.0/11 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
54.246.154.116 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
66.206.25.137 via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto static metric 600 
100.80.0.0/12 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
100.96.0.0/11 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
100.96.1.80/28 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 100.96.1.86 metric 50 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.0.0/12 via 100.96.1.81 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-eb69e037d2ec proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-b14ba2bacde7 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-869ba33d8658 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.65 metric 600 
192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto static scope link metric 600
```

Comment: It sounds like the OpenVPN configuration sends all traffic over the tunnel for the default route.  Which would prevent Internet access while on the VPN if not permitted on the work side of the network.  Can you confirm this with `ip route list` when connected to the VPN and attach that information as an edit to your question?

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks for the suggestion, I added this to my question

Comment: Yep, when connected to the VPN, your system is configured to route everything over the tunnel, that's an OpenVPN configuration option in the server side - you will need to discuss with your admins for OpenVPN adjusting the configuration to NOT route all traffic over the VPN.  It may be a company policy that when on the VPN you can't access the Internet itself and only have access to the resources on that side of the network.  There's ways to manually reconfigure it but I'm not near my computer right now so I can't write the answer for that (it needs screenshots heh)

Comment: Thanks, good to know the issue is not on my side.

Comment: Well, in one sense it is, and in one sense it's not.  Are you calling `openvpn config.ovpn` directly on command line or are you using Network Manager after importing the OpenVPN config?

Comment: I am using the Network manager and importing the config.